# how to handle web SQL queries and xml replies in Python

Tags: python, web-services, xml-parsing

I have a distant database on which I can send SQL select queries through a web service like this:

```
http://aa.bb.cc.dd:85/SQLWEB?query=select+*+from+machine&output=xml_v2
```

which returns

```
<Query>
    <SQL></SQL>
    <Fields>
        <MACHINEID DataType="Integer" DataSize="4"/>
        <NAME DataType="WideString" DataSize="62"/>
        <MACHINECLASSID DataType="Integer" DataSize="4"/>
        <SUBMACHINECLASS DataType="WideString" DataSize="22"/>
        <DISABLED DataType="Integer" DataSize="4"/>
    </Fields>
    <Record>
        <MACHINEID>1</MACHINEID>
        <NAME>LOADER</NAME>
        <MACHINECLASSID>16</MACHINECLASSID>
        <SUBMACHINECLASS>A</SUBMACHINECLASS>
        <DISABLED>0</DISABLED>
    </Record>
    <Record>
    ...
    </Record>
...
</Query>
```

Then I need to insert the records into a local SQL database.

What's the easiest way ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, querys in the url it's a horrible idea for security.**

Use xml libs to parse the xml, and then iterate over the result to add to the db.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('xml file')
root = tree.getroot()    
# root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string) if you use a string
for record in root.findall('Record'):
    MACHINEID = record.get('MACHINEID')
    NAME = record.get('NAME')
    MACHINECLASSID = record.get('MACHINECLASSID')
    SUBMACHINECLASS = record.get('SUBMACHINECLASS')
    DISABLED = record.get('DISABLED')
    #your code to add this result to the db
```

[ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)